# Android recycler view toggle button recycling issue

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am making an app and has a recyclerview for showing user feed. I am using a toggle button for liking posts. When the user opens the app it enables the like button if the status is already liked by the user who is using the app and the user can also like the posts by scrolling down like other socials apps out there.

> The problem is if a toggle button is checked when scrolling down
>    other toggle buttons belongs to other posts are also getting checked.

**Adapter class**

```
 public class topNewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<topNewsRowHolder> {

        private ArrayList<topData> topDataList;
        private Context context;
        private Activity activity;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private View v;
        protected String liked = "success";
        protected String expired = "Expired";




        public topNewsAdapter( ArrayList<topData> listItemList , Activity activity , RecyclerView view) {

            this.topDataList = listItemList;
            this.activity = activity;
            this.recyclerView = view;

        }



        @Override
        public topNewsRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.top_news_row, parent, false);
            context = parent.getContext();
            return new topNewsRowHolder(v , activity); //passed activity



        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final topNewsRowHolder holder, final int position) {


            topData item = topDataList.get(position);

            if(!(item == null)) {

                holder.userName.setText(item.getUserName().toString());
                holder.timer.setText(item.getCreatedTime().toString());
                holder.status.setText(item.getStatus().toString());
                holder.fameCount.setText(item.getLikeCount().toString());
                holder.dislike_Count.setText(item.getDislike_Count().toString());
                holder.statusID.setText(item.getStatusID().toString());



                if(item.getLiked().equals(1)){
                    holder.fameButton.setChecked(true);
                }else if(item.getLiked().equals(0)){
                    holder.fameButton.setChecked(false);
                }



                if(item.getDisliked().equals(1)){
                    holder.disLikeButton.setChecked(true);

                }else if(item.getDisliked().equals(0)){
                    holder.disLikeButton.setChecked(false);
                }





               holder.fameButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked){

                           lRequester(holder.statusID.getText().toString() , "1" , holder.fameCount );
                            dRequester(holder.statusID.getText().toString() , "0" , holder.dislike_Count);

                            holder.fameButton.setChecked(true);


                       }else if(!isChecked){
                            lRequester(holder.statusID.getText().toString() , "0" , holder.fameCount);


                        }
                   }
               });


                holder.disLikeButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked){
                            dRequester(holder.statusID.getText().toString(), "1" ,holder.dislike_Count);
                            lRequester(holder.statusID.getText().toString() , "0" , holder.fameCount);

                            holder.fameButton.setChecked(false);

                        }else if(!isChecked){
                            dRequester(holder.statusID.getText().toString() , "0" , holder.dislike_Count);
                        }
                    }
                });







        }



        }













        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return topDataList.size();
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }




        public void lRequester(String id , String type, final TextView textview){
            Call<responseFD> request = handler.handlerClass.fame(data("u") , data("t") , id , type );
            request.enqueue(new Callback<responseFD>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<responseFD> call, Response<responseFD> response) {
                    if(!response.body().getResponse().isEmpty() && (response.body().getResponse() != null)) {

                        if (response.body().getResponse().equals(expired)) {
                            vlData.getInstance().terminateRunnable();
                            reset();

                        }else if (response.body().getResponse().equals(liked)) {
                            textview.setText(response.body().getLike_count().toString());

                        }


                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<responseFD> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Something Gone Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


        }


        public void dRequester(String id , String type , final TextView textView){
            Call<responseFD> request = handler.handlerClass.disfame(data("u") , data("t") , id , type );
            request.enqueue(new Callback<responseFD>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<responseFD> call, Response<responseFD> response) {
                    if(!response.body().getResponse().isEmpty() && response.body().getResponse() != null) {
                        if (response.body().getResponse().equals(expired)) {
                            vlData.getInstance().terminateRunnable();
                            reset();

                        }else if (response.body().getResponse().equals(liked)) {
                            textView.setText(response.body().getDislike_Count().toString());

                        }
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<responseFD> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("data", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });







        }


        public void reset(){

            Intent i = new Intent(activity , login.class);
            activity.startActivity(i);
            activity.finish();
        }



    }
```

**Rowholder class**

```
 public  class topNewsRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView userName;
    protected TextView timer;
    protected TextView status;
    protected ImageView profilePicHolder;
    protected TextView fameCount;
    protected TextView dislike_Count;
    protected ToggleButton fameButton;
    protected ToggleButton disLikeButton;
    protected View v;
    protected TextView statusID;
    protected Activity activity;
    protected RelativeLayout holderlayout;




    public topNewsRowHolder(View view , Activity activity ){
        super(view);
        v = view;
        this.activity = activity;

        this.userName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.usernameHolder);
        this.timer = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timeHolder);
        this.status = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.status_user);
        this.profilePicHolder = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_holder);
        this.fameCount = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.like_count);
        this.dislike_Count = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dislike_count);
        this.fameButton = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fameButton);
        this.disLikeButton = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.dislikeButton);
        this.statusID = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.statusID);
        this.holderlayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.text);







    }


    }
```

I know this is because of the recycling. How to fix this issue ?. Thanks :)

Comment: You'll need to setLiked and setItemDisliked inside check changed listeners, and call notifyitemChanged(getAdapterPosition()); That ought to solve it. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: use `SparseBooleanArray` [SparseBooleanArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html)

Comment: any example @vrundpurohit ?

Comment: @AlokOmkar in a new listener or the existing ones ?

Comment: Use the existing ones, the ones you are setting on fameButton and dislikeButton

Comment: @AlokOmkar can u show me an example dude ?

Comment: @AlokOmkar that code snippet will check the json whether the user liked the post or not while loading the app and checks the toggle button.

Comment: I understand. Will post a code snippet.

Comment: @AlokOmkar if i put that inside a listener , it needs a click right ?. The problem is with recycling. the position value is getting recycled i think so .

Answer (score 0):

Try this : RecyclerView needs an external variable to keep track of which items are checked, while SparseBooleanArray will work, its tedious.

```
holder.fameButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean IsChecked) { 
        isChecked ? item.setIsLiked(1) : item.setIsLiked(0);
        if(isChecked){
            lRequester(holder.statusID.getText().toString() , "1" , holder.fameCount );
            dRequester(holder.statusID.getText().toString() , "0" , holder.dislike_Count);
        } else if(!isChecked){
            lRequester(holder.statusID.getText().toString() , "0" , holder.fameCount);
        }
        }
     });
```

Comment: dude i am getting these values from json not a Boolean array. It enables the toggle button if the user already liked the post.
 if(item.getLiked().equals(1)){
                    holder.fameButton.setChecked(true);
                }



                if(item.getDisliked().equals(1)){
                    holder.disLikeButton.setChecked(true);

                }

Comment: Doesn't the user have option to like and dislike on checking toggle button?

Comment: yes they do. where the source of these values used in the ternary ?. isChecked ? item.setIsLiked(1) : item.setIsLiked(0); ?

Comment: It is for tracking of like / dislike when user clicks on toggle button.

Comment: item.setIsLiked(1) this one ?. i am asking about the source ?.. :)

Comment: topData item = topDataList.get(position); This is your data. I am assuming you have a variable inside it to keep track of if the user has liked the post or not. As and when the user clicks on the toggle button, you need to set this value to keep track of the toggle state. I wish I could initialize a chat room, can you host a chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120563/discussion-between-alok-omkar-and-jijo-john).

Answer (score 0):

Create a Broker pattern for managind likes within the content feed.

This singleton broken would keep track of each Content feed item id and map it to a state (social or just likes) in a hashmap. And every time there is a reaction (like/unlike/dislike/undislike) happenning to a Content feed item, you trigger the actian using this Broker that also propagates and keeps track of the changes locally. You ahould implement a Broadcaster or a pub-sub pattern to ibform the UI about the changes.

Preferably use a Content Provider with a database for storing the json you are getting from the webserver.

Let me know if you need further clarifications.

---

SocialBroker.java

```
public class SocialBroker extends ISocialBroker {
    //region <!-- Private properties -->
    private static SocialBroker _instance;
    private HashMap<UUID, SocialStatus> _map = new HashMap<>();
    //endregion

    //region <!-- Singleton initializer -->
    public static SocialBroker newInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new SocialBroker();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    private SocialBroker() {};
    //endregion
    // The interface method implemented here
}
```

ISocialBroker.java

```
public interface ISocialBroker {
    public synchronized SocialStatus save(String expiresAt, UUID id, boolean hasLiked, int numberOfLikes, int numberOfComments);
    public SocialStatus lookup(UUID id);
    public synchronized SocialStatus like(UUID id);
    public synchronized SocialStatus unlike(UUID id);

    public HashMap<UUID, SocialStatus> getMap();
    public void loadState(HashMap<UUID, SocialStatus> restoredSocialState);
}
```

OnReactionObserver.java

```
public interface OnReactionObserver {
    void onLikeReaction();
}
```

OnReactionPublisher.java

```
public interface OnReactionPublisher {
    void attachObserver(OnReactionObserver... observer);
    void notifyListeners();
}
```

When you bind the results to your views in your adapter, you save the entries using the broker, then in your like button view, you summon the Broker again to execute the like/unlike/dislike/undislike.

SocialStatus is just a model to keep track of information, that can be serialized, saved, synchronized with an online service.

Hope this points you to the right direction.

Comment: any example dude ?